# Creating an array of bytea in Java to pass to a Postgresql stored procedure

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql

I need to pass an array of bytea to a stored procedure (the declared type if bytea[]).

The data get's passed to my stored procedure, however, I cannot get the individual bytea from the bytea[].  The array_lower and array_upper functions report a dimension of one, but tumb_data[1] always returns NULL.

If I print the whole bytea[] object from my stored proc, I get something that starts with "{{-1,-40,-1,-32,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1", so I know data is making it to the procedure.

This is some example code that shows the problem:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test";
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"andres","xxx");
List<byte[]> thumbData=new ArrayList<byte[]>();
thumbData.add("Test #1".getBytes());
thumbData.add("Test #1".getBytes());
Object[] thumbs=thumbData.toArray();
Array thumbArray=c.createArrayOf("bytea", thumbs);
PreparedStatement stmt=c.prepareStatement("SELECT test_funct(?)");
stmt.setArray(1,thumbArray);
stmt.execute();
```

And this is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_funct(a_bytes bytea[])
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$DECLARE
    v_bytes bytea;
BEGIN
FOR i IN array_lower(a_bytes,1) .. array_upper(a_bytes,1) LOOP 
        v_bytes:= a_bytes[i];
        IF (v_bytes IS NULL) THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'error';
        END IF; 
    END LOOP;

    RETURN true;
END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Finally, here's the log output when I run my test program:

```
2013-02-17 21:03:52 EST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SET extra_float_digits = 3
2013-02-17 21:03:52 EST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE typname = $1
2013-02-17 21:03:52 EST DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '_bytea'
2013-02-17 21:03:52 EST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT e.typdelim FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t, pg_catalog.pg_type e WHERE t.oid = $1 and t.typelem = e.oid
2013-02-17 21:03:52 EST DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '1001'
2013-02-17 21:03:52 EST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT test_funct($1)
2013-02-17 21:03:52 EST DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '{{"\\x3834","\\x313031","\\x313135","\\x313136","\\x3332","\\x3335","\\x3439"},{"\\x3834","\\x313031","\\x313135","\\x313136","\\x3332","\\x3335","\\x3439"}}'
2013-02-17 21:03:52 EST ERROR:  error
2013-02-17 21:03:52 EST STATEMENT:  SELECT test_funct($1)
2013-02-17 21:03:52 EST LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
```

Any idea how to pass this to my stored procedure?

Comment: Can you show your stored procedure?

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Stored procedure language? Proc source? Output of `SELECT`ing the data?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your array has two dimensions; instead of a one dimensional (linear) array of `bytea`, you have a two-dimensional array of `bytea`. Indexing such an array's first dimension will produce an empty result. Note that PostgreSQL arrays of any dimensions still have the basic array data type, there is no `bytea[][]` etc. Use `array_ndims(anyarray)` to get the array dimensions.

Observe one dimensional:

```
WITH t1(ba) AS (VALUES(ARRAY[ '\x0a', '\x0c', '\x0e' ] :: bytea[]))
SELECT ba, ba[1], ba[1][1] FROM t1;
            ba             |  ba  | ba 
---------------------------+------+----
 {"\\x0a","\\x0c","\\x0e"} | \x0a | 
(1 row)
```

vs two-dimensional:

```
WITH t1(ba) AS (VALUES(ARRAY[[ '\x0a', '\x0c', '\x0e' ]] :: bytea[]))
SELECT ba, ba[1], ba[1][1] FROM t1;

             ba              | ba |  ba  
-----------------------------+----+------
 {{"\\x0a","\\x0c","\\x0e"}} |    | \x0a
(1 row)
```

Since you have not shown the full value or your SQL, it's hard to say more.

If you suspect a JDBC driver problem it would help if you could perhaps provide a self-contained compileable test case that demonstrated the problem, including SQL script to set up a test database.

**Please show the actual SQL that gets run** including the parameters passed. You can get this from the PostgreSQL log files with `log_statement` enabled.

Comment: Craig, yes, in fact is being sent as a two dimensional array.  Do you know how to send it as one dimensional array of bytea? Running the exact same code with data type "text" instead of "bytea" yields a one dimensional array.